# How to handle the visibility of variables in Python if a setter is needed but not a getter

Tags: python, variables, naming-conventions, visibility

This problem if fairly general (in terms of what variables it applies to), but I will use my specific problem (a `set`) to ask about it.

As far as I know, you are discouraged from using getter and setter for your variables in Phyton and should - if possible - allow others to simply access your variable directly.
I now have a class called `Environment` which has a `set` containing `Creature`s. Each time I add a `Creature` I need to tell it to which `Environment` it belongs.
Now I see the following options:

- I call the `set` `_creatures` and provide the methods `add_creature(creature)` and `get_all_creatures()`. This is the Java way I would be used to, but actually no getter is required for my `set`, so should I really provide such a getter?
- Like the last option, only I don't provide a getter and one must access the variable directly even though its name starts with a `"_"`
- I call the `set` `creatures` and therefore make the set publicly accessible, but denote in the documentation that one should always set a `Creature`s `Environment` when adding it to `creatures`.
- I call the `set` `creatures`, provide a method `add_creature(creature)` and denote in the documentation that only this method should be used adding elements
- Use some observable `set` and listen for new elements being added (if so, please provide the package for such a `set` as I couldn't find any)

Is any of these options what I am *supposed* to do? If not, what would be the desired solution?

Comment: Any working code example?

Comment: could you elaborate as to why you think this question would benefit from a code example? The question is about naming conventions and I really don't really see how a code example would help to clarify it.

Comment: Because it is easy to understand each other clear when working on a real code example. Anyway. Python doesn't really provide an encapsulation. So 5 of your methods are the same.Although all of your protection, anyone can reach anytime by anyway to your set. So you must change your approach. All 5 of your examples are good for strict type object oriented languages but python is loose type and an object based(not only oriented) language.So these dont work.